# How to make new document with JXA?

Tags: javascript-automation

How to make new document and close? Need this to workaround apple automation buggy insanity. What I try is this:

```
var app = Application('Keynote')
var doc = app.make(new document)  // How to write this correctly?
doc.close({saving: 'no'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppleScript and JavaScript syntax is completely different. You have to think more in terms of JavaScript

For example JXA doesn't understand `make(new)`.

You have to create an *instance* from the *class* name (note the uppercase spelling) and then call `make()`.
Actually the `var` keywords and the trailing semicolons are not needed.

```
keynote = Application('Keynote')
keynote.activate()
newDocument = keynote.Document().make()
```

Within the parentheses of `Document()` you can pass parameters similar to AppleScript’s `with properties` for example

```
newDocument = keynote.Document({
    documentTheme: keynote.themes["Gradient"], 
    width:1920, 
    height:1080
})
```

AppleScript’s multiple word properties like `document theme` are written as one *camelCased* word.

To close the frontmost document write

```
keynote.documents[0].close()
```

Comment: Could you please tell where did you get this documentation? And thank you for your answer!

Comment: Actually from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW1) and the [JXA Cookbook](https://github.com/JXA-Cookbook/JXA-Cookbook/wiki) on GitHub